# using api action in map in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have an id and want to get the name though id, so I use action in map function here is a code

```
this.props.getInvoiceInfo.invoiceItem.map((wit, i) =>{ 
    {this.props.getJewelleryName(wit.itemId)}
}
```

Comment: what you want to ask exactly ?

Comment: What is currently your problem? The action isn't working? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i get  this error Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: getJewelleryName is an action where the data get jewelleryName though api.

Comment: then your api is returning some object and you just rendering that ?

Comment: yes exactly, api return only string eg: "xyz Name"

Answer (score 0):

OK, suppose i have some data like ID, name in my props.

and i am trying to get name by its id.

```
name={this.props.getInvoiceInfo.invoiceItem.map(
  ({id, name})=>({value:id,label:name})
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you mentioned in the comment, it looks like your code is present in return inside render which is wrong. It is anti-pattern to call APIs(side-effects) anywhere in the render. You may need a handler or some hooks/lifecycles.

Comment: I used handler and result is displaying in the console but how to print that response to the expected place `{this.getdata(wit.jewelleryName)} getdata = id => {
               this.props.getJewelleryName(id)
               .then(response =>{
                console.log(response)
                return response;
               })
               .catch(function(error) {
  console.error(error);
});`

Comment: Why not set the response in some state and place it wherever required